# Как передавать входные аргументы, которые будут использоваться потом, при запуске контейнера?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

Есть **python** скрипт со своими зависимостями, список которых находится в **requirements.txt.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам скрипт при его запуске через консоль принимает один **входной параметр.**

Я хочу создать на основе этого контейнер.

Итак можно ли сделать так, чтобы при запуске контейнера передавать тот самый параметр, который необходим исполняемому скрипту?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, можно.

Если вы хотите передать этот параметр, как аргумент, для это нужно использовать `ENTRYPOINT`: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint.

Например, у нас есть такой скрипт для тестов `test.py`:

```py
import sys

print(sys.argv)
```

И `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "test.py"]
```

Тогда при запуске такого образа `docker run --rm <image> hello world` в консоль будет выдано: `['test.py', 'hello', 'world']`.

Также можно передавать параметры через переменные окружения.

Например, скрипт:

```py
import os

print(os.environ['TEST'])
```

При запуске его этой командой `docker run --rm -e TEST=hello <image>` выведет `hello`, значение которые мы установили параметром `-e`.